# Animate Content change in PivotItem

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 project. I am changing `Content` in a `PivotItem` (from a `Grid` to a `WebBrowser`). Is there a way to animate that change with a turn-the-page effect or slide-from-side effect?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rethink this approach. First and foremost, using a browser control within a pivot will cause all sorts of UI problems with touch gestures. If a user swipes left or right will their intention be to navigate the pivot or adjust the view in the browser? Microsoft will probably reject this implementation. You should look into navigating away from your pivot page and to new page containing a browser control. Using page transitions during navigation is trivial and available in the Windows Phone Toolkit (formally Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone).

http://phone.codeplex.com

Comment: I actually have used a webbrowser in a pivot in my own apps which has passed certification. But I agree that it can definetly cause some confusion for the user unless you set IsHitTestVisible  to false (disables scroll, pan, zoom etc of the webbrowser control)

Answer (score 0):

As Inkog said, it might be a bad idea to use a webbrowser control in a pivot item. But if you still want to do it, you can change the content and then call the page transitions in the [Windows Phone toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) in code to get a page animation effect, like slide in or turnstile.

Here is a great guide for using the navigation transitions in the [WP toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) for WP7, but I would guess it would be similair the toolkit for WP8:
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide

Otherwise you can create your own [animations using storyboards, which is quite easy using Expression Blend](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinash/archive/2011/12/21/flipping-card-animation-for-windows-phone-7-using-expression-blend.aspx) and then run those animations when you change the content.